# Issue adjusting figsize with matplotlib barh subplot

Tags: matplotlib, figsize

I've tried specifying in a few ways but have not been able to get this figure any bigger than what's shown.

[image]

```
category_names = ['Database', 'Frontend', 'QA', 'ML', 'Fullstack']
labels = list(final_df.index)
data = np.array(final_df.iloc[:, 1:])
data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
category_colors = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(np.linspace(0, 1000, data.shape[1]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(100,75))
ax.invert_yaxis()
# ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlim(0, 200)

for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
    widths = data[:, i]
    starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
    ax.barh(labels, widths, left=starts, height=0.5,
            label=colname, color=color)
    xcenters = starts + widths / 2

    r, g, b, _ = color
    text_color = 'white' if r * g * b < 0.5 else 'darkgrey'
    for y, (x, c) in enumerate(zip(xcenters, widths)):
        ax.text(x, y, str(int(c)), ha='center', va='center',
                color=text_color, fontsize=15)
```

If I make the figsize any bigger, the kernel dies and I've tried adjusting height and np.linspace params, as well as trying to set size with fig.set_size_inches. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: That is 100 inches by 75 inches.  How are you trying to save it or display it? 100" monitors are quite rare.

Comment: haha, true. I should have adjusted before posting but I did start with a normal size. I believe it was 24 by 20.

Comment: For an issue like this, you'd probably need some actual data. Would you like to present some sample data?

Comment: 24"x20" is still bigger than most monitors.  Also, how are you trying to save it or display it?

Comment: I often plot 24X20 plots? They're definitely on the bigger side, but they don't take up my whole screen? I'm not sure what to make of that. I'm displaying with Jupyter Notebook. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I'd say update matplotlib, pandas and restart jupyter kernel and clear all outputs.